# What pull requester should do to revert bad commits

Tags: git, github

I have pull request to review, and I see that some files are not needed i.e `.tmp` etc.   also have one file pushed which should not be edited.

Which git operation pull requester should do, to fix this problems?
From my perspective I see branch with one commit, cannot separate bad commits from good one. What if pull requester also doesn't have local commits? What if he has?

Comment: Ask the developer to fix the problems, and push the changes to his/her PR branch.

Comment: @BryceDrew:  I'd argue that the question is more about Git than anything else anyway, since it involves the pull requester submitting fixes to their PR without the intervention of GitHub.

Comment: @Makoto Pull Request is not a feature of git, right?

Comment: I can change `pull request` to `branch` and it doesn't change anything because to fix this git operation are needed or manual fix

Comment: @BryceDrew:  It isn't, but the actual *fix* involves more Git than GitHub.  Besides, for all you know it could be some other service which offers pull requests which isn't *necessarily* GitHub related (although in all reality it likely is).

Comment: @Makoto I understand now what you mean. For me there is a distinct difference in methodology between a `Branch I need to edit` and a `Pull request to Review`.

Answer (score 3):

There's more than one way to do it, and the right way will depend on your contribution policy.

The pull requester (user submitting the PR) can fix the PR in any number of ways. Remember that the important part of a PR is the *aggregate* change created by all the commits in the PR. If a line is added in one commit and removed in another, the aggregate change won't show that line at all.

So the question is, how do you want this PR to show up in your change history? Some projects like to have PRs "squashed" to a single commit which is the aggregate changeset (the pull requester can do this using an interactive rebase: `git rebase -i HEAD~n` where `n` is the number of commits in the PR branch). Since you're only seeing one commit, I'm guessing this is how your project operates. Others consider interactive rebasing and squashing to be "rewriting history" and believe in merging the set of changes even if they revert each other.

If you want a clean history, and it looks like you do, you can ask the pull requester to clean up their branch. They can do this either by adding a commit fixing the problems and then squashing the branch, or by making changes in their working tree and updating their already-squashed commit. They can then force-push their branch, which will have the effect of updating the PR with the updated, "cleaner" branch.

But there's more than one way to do it, so this is *an* answer, not *the* answer.

Comment: From my perspective I want squashed commit. But problem here is how to remove not needed file from branch (file doesn't exists on master) and how to remove not needed change on file that exists on master.

Comment: Once you squash the developer changes into a single commit it is quite easy to `amend` this commit by removing the unneeded files and using `git commit --amend`.

Comment: Yes. So the pull requester should make the changes in their branch which resolve the problem, commit it, re-squash the branch, and force push.

Comment: Or amend the squashed commit, as @DarinDimitrov says.